# MySQL Database discord.js

Tags: mysql, discord, discord.js

It's my first time working with a database and I ran into a problem. I want to make an embed with information from a database. The Bot can only read those informations and not change anything. I set up the Bot with the Database using `npm mysql`. Now I got my Database connection ready and the embed ready but I don't really know how to combine those two things. In the Value fields from the embed should the information from the database go. For example, in the database there's a column with male players, and because they change throughout the day I want to make an embed that shows exactly how many male players there are when somebody types in the command `info`.

Database Connection Code (everything is private for a reason):

```js
    const connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : 'private',
        port     : 'private',
        user     : 'private',
        password : 'private',
        database : 'private',
        charset  : 'private'
      });


    connection.connect()
```

My Code for the embed (in the value fields should the information from the database go):

```js
    if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'info')) {
         
        const sembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()

        .setTitle('Info:')
        .setThumbnail('png')
        .setColor('GOLD')
        .addFields(
            {name: 'Players:', value: ''},
            {name: '', value: '', inline: true},
            {name: '', inline: true},
            {name: '', value: '', inline: true},
        )
        .setTimestamp()

        message.channel.send({embeds: [sembed]})
      }
```

Comment: why you put every value as private ?

Comment: Did you notice that there's and extra quote (`'`)? You can see where with syntax highlighting

Comment: Changed that in the code, ty

Answer (score 1):

For database connection use those line of code with proper value.

```
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    port     : 'your my sql port',
    user     : 'my sql username',
    password : 'user password',
    database : 'database name',
    charset  : 'utf8mb4'
  });

connection.connect()
```

Hope that may be help to you any query ask me.

Comment: I did that but I put everything in `private` for obvious reasons. The problem I got is not with the database connection itself but with filling the values in the embed because there should the information from the database go. For example, in the database there's a column with male players, and because they change throughout the day I want to make an embed that shows exactly how many male players there are when somebody types in the command `info`

Comment: For that you have to store all info then you have to filter them by male or female category .

Comment: I'm so sorry but i have no idea what you mean or what i should do. Like i said that's my first time working with a database

Comment: then you have to learn sql first . for that you can go w3schools.com

Comment: If you mean the database everything is set up there. Everything is filterd and i just need to become the information in the embed

Comment: yes . because data is main. if you have data then you can play what ever you want.

Comment: My problem is that i have a database from a friend that is already set up(everything is finished there). The only thing i have to do is make an embed in discord that shows exactly how many people are right now in a specific group for example in the mans group. The problem i have now is that i got the database connection from him and my embed but the `value fields` in there are empty because i don't know what to put in there because i never worked with a database and usually i would just write my own thing in there but i can't do that bc i need the database infos